# How to use React.Children.map with React.cloneElement with flow@0.53.0

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

If I type the parent component's children as `Node`, then it says that `children` is the wrong type to pass to `React.Children.map`. However, if I type it as `ChildrenArray<any>`, then it says that the type I'm passing to `React.cloneElement` is incorrect.

[Scenario 1](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThxcAC2AAbACaUAdgH4AXJiowAdAGFx0uQEEoUZEwA8yWUwB8AGjoBfenVwS06ACpZU8LAA8YWWVLo2HjqGiSQsv4wxpwQ3BYCQnBgXKjKsdz0wklyUlhQABQAlInCwpQwAK5Qsiohmtoy-mogyGAFMOKoailx3WKSTbJWIo1wPAlJZXX4ak4QkQCiElggUQUD0iP8tkVTcEVZcLZ2DMbunhZJxqhgZhYEEBDGAPS399fvshYARshQry+V1eFxgFiAA):

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ChildrenArray<any>,
};

class Test extends React.Component<Props> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => 
      React.cloneElement(child, {})
    );
  }
}

<Test>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</Test>
```

[Scenario 2](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThxcAC2AAbACaUAdgH4AXHAByEKVgA0dAL706uCWnQAVLKnhYAHjCyyp6bHhgA6AMIlIsuzAA8nCG4APgEhODAuVGUA7nphMLkNKAAKAEpQ4WFKGABXKFlMKlc3cWk5FxBkMGSYcVQXCMD6sUkZO00RUqk4HhCwzMLnF0MIbwBRCSwQH2SW6Q7+HVT+uFS4uB1dBl8zCyCw31QwZFkggggIXwB6I5P94UPj04AjZChr29O6a92YIKA):

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: Node,
};

class Test extends React.Component<Props> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => 
      React.cloneElement(child, {})
    );
  }
}

<Test>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</Test>
```

Comment: Your first example errors with just https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThxcAC2AAbACaUAdgC5MVGADoAwuOlyAglCjImAHmSymAPgA0dAL706uCWnQAVLKnhYAHjCyyp6bDxVNRJIWV8YQ04IbjMBawZDV3czIThDVDATMwIICEMAekzstIys2TMAI2QoQuKKukLkmDMgA, but passes with https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThxcAC2AAbACaUAdgH4AXJiowAdAGFx0uQEEoUZEwA8yWUwB8AGjoBfenVwS06ACpZU8LAA8YWWVLo2HjqGiSQsv4wxpwQ3BYCtgzG7p4WQnApHjAA9OnGOakwFkA so definitely seems weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the first example is the use of `React.ChildrenArray<any>`. It isn't really the case that anything can be used in there, since they have to be elements that React can understand as Nodes. If I change that to `React.ChildrenArray<*>` to [let React infer the allowed type](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFjoC8cA3nThxcAC2AAbACaUAdgH4AXJiowAdAGFx0uQEEoUZEwA8CAHwAaOgF96dXBLToAKllTwsADxhZZU9Nh46hokkLK+MMacENxmAkJwYFyoytHc9MIJclJYUAAUAJTxwsKUMACuULIqQZraMr5qIMhgeTDiqGpJMZ1ikg2yFiL1cDxxCSU1+GoOEOEAohJYIBF5fdJD-NYFE3AFGXDWNgzGru5mCcaoYMiyZgQQEMYA9Ne3F8JXN3cARshQLzedzoLzOMDMQA), it seems to work fine.